# SQL request for a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

**models.py**

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_name, ])

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'countries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**0001_initial.py**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Country',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[countries.validators.validate_name])),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'countries',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

**sql**

```
(venv) michael@michael:~/Documents/PyCharmProjects/db/db$ python manage.py sqlmigrate countries 0001_initial
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Country
--
-- (no-op)
COMMIT;
```

Could you tell me whether this sql reflects the model or not? If not, how can it happen? And will it produce in the database?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sql to apply to the db because of `managed = False`.

That is, running `migrate` does not change the db.